# SQLAlchemy : DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250001 (08001): Incorrect username or password was specified

Tags: sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: ****.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.

I got the above error when I tried to connect to snowflake using sqlalchemy . My credentials has @ . So I tried using urllib.parse . Still it is not able to connect

Below is the code I used

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
#from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry

registry.register('snowflake', 'snowflake.sqlalchemy', 'dialect')


# Establish the connection to the Snowflake database
snowflake_user = 'my_name.last@****.com'
snowflake_password = 'password@123'
snowflake_account = '****.us-east-1'
snowflake_client_prefetch_threads = 4

sf = 'snowflake://{}:{}@{}'.format(snowflake_user, snowflake_password, snowflake_account)
engine = create_engine(sf)
print(sf)
print(engine)
# alchemy_snow_connection = engine.connect()

snowflake_user = urllib.parse.quote_plus(snowflake_user)
snowflake_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(snowflake_password)
sf = 'snowflake://{}:{}@{}'.format(snowflake_user, snowflake_password, snowflake_account)
engine = create_engine(sf)
print(sf)
print(engine)
alchemy_snow_connection = engine.connect()
```

Can someone please help me to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Use [sqlalchemy.engine.URL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL) to build your connection URL. It will take care of all the escaping for you.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_url = URL.create(
    "snowflake",
    username=snowflake_user,
    password=snowflake_password,
    host=snowflake_account,
)
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Comment: thanks for the response . I tired using this . As you said escaping is happening . but still getting invalid credentials . Does that has anything to do with OKTA Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are most likely passing the user coming from Okta to be authenticated as an internal user.
To ensure that the user credentials are validated from Okta itself, pass the following parameter in the code:

```
 authenticator=https://<okta_account_name>.okta.com
```